# Encrypt and decrypt query strings in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using MVC3. I have a couple of pages which does not require authentication but these pages have querystrings which could be tampered. I am planning to encrypt these urls when sending to users and decrypting it back when they hit it, what is the best way to encrypt and decrypt query strings in MVC3? Send me a pointer If there is any module that I can reuse...

Comment: If your querystrings are vulnerable to tampering, then surely you are relying on security by obscurity anyway? Isn't it better to not encrypt the querystring and just apply appropriate permissioning on the server - you are already authenticating the users, it shouldn't be too hard to do.

Comment: Thanks David for your response, but I can't authenticate these page neither can i add permissioning  on the server, These are free info collection forms which end up updating the DB. Take an example of collecting some information from a guest invited to an event but the guest does not to login to update the info, what to do in such scenario?

Comment: Sorry, misread your question. "does not require". Got it. Suggest you introduce something like a Guid for each guest, an unguessable code that they can use in a URL without you having to go the encryption route.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you trust in another kind of storage mechanism instead of a query string?. You could pass the information over a POST operation, there are several ways to do that, such as cache or other. Post automatically puts that information on the request header, and its hidden to the ussers, also if your site is over SSL connection, that information is encripted.

You could improve security to your site against malware petitions with integrated MVC security features, such @Html.AntiForgeryToken(), this prevents that a malitious site tries to bypass your system impersonating a real petition. In a nut shell this means that a unique ID is printed on the form header when the form is sent to the client, and if the ID does not equals the one that the server expects, simply the request is ignored.

Heres an interesting post that could help you.

https://sites.google.com/site/muazkh/asp-net-mvc-security-and-hacking-defense-in-depth

Best regards!